# How to access particular element in list in java

Tags: java, activejdbc, javalite

I am looping a list to get particular ids off the list array:

This is list I am looping:

```
for(int i =0 ;i<listOfIds.size();i++) {
    System.out.println("list of post_ids " + listOfIds.get(i));
}
```

After looping the output is:

```
list of post_ids Model: com.soul.seeker.models.PostsCategories, table: 'posts_categories', attributes: {post_id=184}
list of post_ids Model: com.soul.seeker.models.PostsCategories, table: 'posts_categories', attributes: {post_id=185}
```

Now I want to access particular element i.e. `attributes: {post_id=185}`. How do I do that?

**Update:** The class List is of type `LazyList` from http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/

Comment: What class is each element in your list?  And what methods does that class have, for retrieving attributes?

Comment: What is the signature of the list and what is the structure of that object

Comment: I asked the class of the elements in your list, not the list itself. You still haven't answered. This question is about how to extract something from the objects themselves,  not from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, create new object in the loop with the criteria you want and use equals between the object you want with the object in the list like this:

```
for(int i =0 ;i<listOfIds.size();i++) {
     my_object obj = new my_object ();
     obj.(set criteria you want )
     if(listOfIds.get(i).equals(obj)){
       "you got it";
     }
    System.out.println("list of post_ids " + listOfIds.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: The chances are extremely remote that something like this will actually work for OP.  But since he/she _still_ hasn't told us anything about the objects in the list, we really can't tell yet.

Comment: Updated the question with list type

Answer (score 1):

Since you are operating on ActiveJDBC models, you can:

```
  PostsCategories c;   
  for(int i =0 ;i<listOfIds.size();i++) {
       if(listOfIds.get(i).get("post_id").equals(185))}
          c = listOfIds.get(i); 
          System.out.println("Found it: " + c);
       }
  }
```

Comment: I have `[185,186,187....]`. Check my answer below. What do you recommend?

Comment: your question and answer do not offer much context to go by. I had to guess you are using ActiveJDBC models from your log. Can you add more information on what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were methods on the API. I thought it was normal `List`. So anyway, I figured it out this way:

```
List postIds = listOfIds.collect("post_id");
String query2 = "Select * from post Where id IN (";
for(int i =0 ; i < postIds.size(); i++) {
  query2 = query2 + "'" +postIds.get(i) + "'" + ",";
}
query2 = query2.substring(0, query2.length()-1);
query2 = query2 + ")";
```